# "Removing leftover files … Unknown user 'uuidd'. [FAIL]" on a fresh Arch Linux installation

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, startup, uuid

I just fresh installed Arch Linux reecently and when booting i can spot a warning:

```
Removing leftover files  [BUSY] [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/uuidd.conf:1] Unknown user 'uuidd'. [FAIL]
```

What could this be? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reinstalling `util-linux` will fix it:

```
pacman -Syu util-linux
```

Comment: Wow how did you know this? It looks like my package hac been broken  or something like that.